# Joining postcodes to coordinates in a .csv file

Tags: qgis, coordinates, csv, merge, attribute-joins

I have a .csv of land registry sales data that includes full addresses and postcodes.

I'm trying to geocode all the data so that I can plot it in QGIS but my issue is that I have 2 million records that I'm not sure I can feasibly run through any commercial geocoders without paying heaps (if anybody has any ideas let me know)

Instead I've downloaded Ordinance Survey's code point dataset which lists coordinates for all of the postcodes in Britain. I'm hoping that there is some way that I can join those records with those in my landreg dataset so that I can have some degree of accuracy in plotting my points.

Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Have you looked at existing QGIS join questions?

Comment: I would look into getting a local postgis database set up, loading the spatial data, and doing some sql spatial!

Answer (score 2):

Recently, I needed to geocode thousands of addresses. I ended up using [Excel Geocoding Tool](http://excelgeocodingtool.com/) which is able to code 65k entries in one run. If splitting your original data to ~20 subparts is acceptable, this might be an option for you. You only need Bing Maps API key and to enable macros in your Excel, the rest is quite straightforward. (It has a problem if there are special characters in addresses, so you might want to get rid of any diacritics in there if present.) Works surprisingly well and precisely. 2-3 entries/second.