# Plot large batch of points without coodinates or geocoding

Tags: qgis, coordinates, geocoding, latitude-longitude, address

I have a list of 50,000 addresses with no Lat/Lon data. I would like to plot these points over a boundaries shapefile. Most geocoding services limit you to 2,500 - 15,000 geocode without paying.

Is there a way to plot these points without geocoding? Perhaps turn the list of addresses into some KML file?

Comment: There was a similar question in the past: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225148/joining-postcodes-to-coordinates-in-a-csv-file Where are your adresses from (country, state, city)?

Comment: What format are your addresses in? Is it one column? Or is it separated into  Address, City, State, Zip (or similar format)?